# Android app using Facebook login: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated Facebook login in my app, but when trying to get the name out of the basic info of the logged in user, I get:

```
{
  Response:  responseCode: 400, 
  graphObject: null, 
  error: {
  HttpStatus: 400, 
  errorCode: 2500, 
  errorType: OAuthException, 
  errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
    }, 
isFromCache:false
}
```

I logged my session token and its expiration date and it is not null nor expired. I tried replacing session with getActiveSession() but that didn't fix anything.

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
if (state.isOpened()) {

    final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            "fbInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()){
        Log.i("sessionToken", session.getAccessToken());
        Log.i("sessionTokenDueDate", session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString());
    }

    new Request(session, "/me?fields=name", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    try {
                        prefs.edit().putString("name", graphResponse.getString("name")).commit();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                                "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

    new Request(session, "/me?fields=quotes", null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    try {
                        prefs.edit().putString("quotes", graphResponse.getString("quotes")).commit();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                                "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (state.isOpened())
{
    Log.i("Facebook", "Logged in...");

    new Request(session, "me/photos",getRequestParameters(), null, new Callback()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {


        }
    }).executeAsync();

....


private Bundle getRequestParameters() 
{
       Bundle parameters = new Bundle(1);
       parameters.putString("fields", "images,other");
       return parameters;
}
```

Comment: I am using the same code given by you. But still getting the same error. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Its giving me the response now but data is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Am i implementing ***4.6.0 FacebookSDK*** and phasing these error but after manage proper structure of classes got success..!!

**AccessToken** Class object's initialize after **GraphRequest** class & inside  **GraphRequest** use object of **AccessToken**

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        System.out.println("object>>" + object);
                        System.out.println("response>>" + response.toString());

                    }
                });
```